# SQLAlchemy caching now() in execute query

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Minimal test case:

```
db = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgres://foo@localhost/bar')
con=db.connect()
con.execute("select now();").first()
sleep(60)
con.execute("select now();").first()
```

The two execute statements return the same value, even though what time "now" is has changed.  I think it's the time I ran db.connect().

I've also used queries of the form

```
select * from table where ts > (now() - interval '1 hour');
```

and they show similar problems.  If I add rows with recent timestamps, they show up.  So it's the *value of now()* that's being cached.  The actual query *is* being freshly executed.  It's just the wrong query.

How do I turn this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [different functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) for the current timestamp in PostgreSQL. From the docs:

> ```
> transaction_timestamp()
> statement_timestamp()
> clock_timestamp()
> timeofday()
> now()
> ```
>
> `transaction_timestamp()` is equivalent to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, but is
>   named to clearly reflect what it returns. `statement_timestamp()`
>   returns the start time of the current statement (more specifically,
>   the time of receipt of the latest command message from the client).
>   `statement_timestamp()` and `transaction_timestamp()` return the same
>   value during the first command of a transaction, but might differ
>   during subsequent commands. `clock_timestamp()` returns the actual
>   current time, and therefore its value changes even within a single SQL
>   command. `timeofday()` is a historical PostgreSQL function. Like
>   `clock_timestamp()`, it returns the actual current time, but as a
>   formatted text string rather than a timestamp with time zone value.
>   `now()` is a traditional PostgreSQL equivalent to
>   `transaction_timestamp()`.

You probably want `statement_timestamp()`.